# Simulate mouse clicks at a certain position on inactive window in Java?

Tags: java, click, position, simulate

Anyways, I'm building a bot to run in the background. This bot requires me to click. Of course, I want to be able to do other things while the bot is running.

So I was wondering if it was possible for me to simulate a mouse click at a certain position on an inactive window.

If this is possible, I would greatly appreciate it if any of you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[java.awt.Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

Clicking into an active window is going to activate it, though.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this class works for clicking on inactive windows

Comment: why? it drives the mouse pointer by screen coordinates, and then 'clicks' (the coordinates are screen ones)

Comment: The problem is, it has to be in the background.
Is there any way I can have it simulate clicks while it's in the background?

Comment: Well, so the frame is actually minimized (for instance), you don't have much of a chance, simulating alt+tab, taking a screenshot, processing to see if the title is there and ultimately running it. Alternatively, use more than a single monitor and keep the window in front all the time... starting a VM (not java) and running its own OS w/ a virtual screen can be an option too. What you want is running a robot but interfering meanwhile.