# How can I simulate a mouse click at a certain position on the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, click, mouse

What I want to do is to manipulate the mouse. It will be a simple macro for my own purposes. So it will move my mouse to certain position on the screen and click like I am clicking with certain interval.

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242409/simulate-mouse-clicks-at-a-certain-position-on-inactive-window-in-c-sharp/8242484#8242484) be what you need ? Also, as someone suggested in the comments, you may wanna use UIAutomation.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Here's a code that is using unmanaged functions to simulate mouse clicks :

```
//This is a replacement for Cursor.Position in WinForms
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

//This simulates a left mouse click
public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
{
    SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
}
```

To keep the mouse pressed for a specific duration you can `Sleep()` the thread that is executing this function, for example  :

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
```

The above code will keep the mouse pressed for 1 second unless the user presses the releases the mouse button. **Also, make sure to not execute this code on the main UI thread as it will cause it to hang**.

Comment: This is FAR simplier than other solutions I have seen here. Thanks

Comment: This code works fine to bring the pointer to the desired coordinates on the screen but for some reason the click does not work for me. Any idea why?

Comment: Here you can have the codes for other mouse buttons : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 10):

You can move by XY position. Example below:

```
windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New System.Drawing.Point(Button1.Location.X + Me.Location.X + 50, Button1.Location.Y + Me.Location.Y + 30)
```

To click, you can use the below code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData,             uint dwExtraInf);
private void btnSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt16(txtX.Text);//set x position 
        int y = Convert.ToInt16(txtY.Text);//set y position 
        Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);//make left button down
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);//make left button up
    }
```

Credit to [JOHNYKUTTY](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/501540-simulate-mouse-movements-click-operations-c#post3639040)

Comment: The question is on WPF, not Forms.

Comment: does not work : windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New System.Drawing.Point(Button1.Location.X + Me.Location.X + 50, Button1.Location.Y + Me.Location.Y + 30)  . also i tried this at forms not mention to will not work at wpf