# Simulate mouse click at a point on screen

Tags: c#, winforms

See figure image bellow
For example, my cursor at black spot, but I want to simulate mouse click at red spot without moving my cursor to red spot. How ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFs20.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I simulate a mouse click at a certain position on the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272681/how-can-i-simulate-a-mouse-click-at-a-certain-position-on-the-screen)

Answer (score 0):

1. Scan through the bitmap and find the red spot using [Bitmap.GetPixel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. Invoke mouse click using [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)