# c# programmatically mouse click on to other screen

Tags: c#, mouseevent

On the 2nd screen on my left I have to programmatically click on point (-850, 35). I have also assigned a shortcut F11 for this, but every time I press F11 the specified point is not clicked, only the first time. The code is as follows:

```
public class ClickOnPointTool
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, ref Point lpPoint);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);
    internal struct INPUT
    {
        public UInt32 Type;
        public MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT Data;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MOUSEINPUT Mouse;
    }
    internal struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public uint MouseData;
        public uint Flags;
        public uint Time;
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    }

    public static void ClickOnPoint(IntPtr wndHandle, Point clientPoint)
    {
        var oldPos = new Point(-850, 35);
        ClientToScreen(wndHandle, ref clientPoint);


        Cursor.Position = new Point(-850, 35);
        var inputMouseDown = new INPUT
        {
            Type = 0
        };
        inputMouseDown.Data.Mouse.Flags = 0x0002;
        var inputMouseUp = new INPUT
        {
            Type = 0
        };
        inputMouseUp.Data.Mouse.Flags = 0x0004;
        var inputs = new[] { inputMouseDown, inputMouseUp };
        SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
        Cursor.Position = oldPos;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272681/how-can-i-simulate-a-mouse-click-at-a-certain-position-on-the-screen

Comment: @Dennis - Yes I tried. But unfortunatelly the same thing happened.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: it works on the first click but not on the second? Have you had a chance to debug your code? Let's figure this out together!

Comment: You haven't specified values for `inputMouseDown.Data.Mouse.X`, `inputMouseDown.Data.Mouse.Y`,  `inputMouseUp.Data.Mouse.X`, `inputMouseUp.Data.Mouse.Y`.