# Synchronize click on group of buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce

I am developing my first Windows embedded Compact 7 application. It is c# and .net 3.5
I have a group of buttons. When one of the buttons is clicked, the effect wanted is, that all of the buttons seem to be clicked at the same time. 
Solutions I found till now, like

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

or even better

```
button1.Performclick
```

seem not to be avalable on WEC7.

Or do I oversee something, that would make them available?

Comment: I assume you are looking for the graphical feedback (ie all buttons appear pressed) on all of the other buttons and not just the code behind the other buttons run?

Comment: You are right, it is all about the graphical feedback

Comment: How about this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242409/simulate-mouse-clicks-at-a-certain-position-on-inactive-window-in-c-sharp/8242484#8242484

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It is not exactly what i was hoping to find, but it may be usable..